# How do I get a DISTINCT value from my paginate statement?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

```
$this->Release->recursive = 0;
        $this->paginate['Release']['joins'] =
                       array(
                        array(
                            'table' => ' game_potential_amazon_matches',
                            'alias' => 'PotentialAmazonMatch',
                            'type' => 'inner',
                            'conditions' =>
                            array(
                                'PotentialAmazonMatch.release_id = Release.id'
                                )
                            )
                        );
        $this->set('releases', $this->paginate('Release'));
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Release with Potential Amazon Matches)');
```

I am getting multiple records and would just like to get distinct by Release.id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `DISTINCT in fields` in that case.

just after `conditions` array use `fields` array like

`fields => array('DISTINCE Release.id','field 2','field 3',...etc)`